# Replace one column by values of the same column in anther table in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, one big and one small. Both contain columns `ID` and `EffectiveDate`.

The bigger table has more other columns and of course more rows than the smaller table.

Under the condition that `ID` for both tables are the same, the `EffectiveDate` column is earlier in the small table than the big table. I want to replace the `EffectiveDate` in the big table by the value of the `EffectiveDate` column from the small table.

What should I do?

Comment: Writing code would be a good start.

Comment: Those "things" in a table are **columns** (not *variables*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a **very basic** SQL query....

```
UPDATE bt
SET EffectiveDate = st.EffectiveDate
FROM dbo.BiggerTable bt
INNER JOIN dbo.SmallerTable st ON bt.ID = st.ID
-- maybe you also need this condition, if not *ALL* EffectiveDate values in the 
-- smaller table are indeed before the values in the bigger table
WHERE st.EffectiveDate < bt.EffectiveDate
```

Comment: Spot on, but I believe he'd also need `WHERE st.EffectiveDate < bt.EffectiveDate` based on his comments.

Comment: @JiggsJedi: possibly - I wasn't clear whether that's already the case anyway, for all rows (when reading the post....)

Comment: I hear you, it is poorly worded.

Comment: Thank you so much! I started using SQL a week ago. Your query is simple and does the job!!!!!!!